# Flex: build error - runtime-shared-library-path

Tags: apache-flex, build

I recently switched a Flex project over to using RSLs. It built fine for quite a while but has recently dug its heels in and is giving me this error:

```
configuration variable 'runtime-shared-library-path' requires a value for 'rsl-url'
```

I went through all the flex XML files I could find and either this value doesn't exist or there are entries available for it. Nowhere did I see a <rs-url></rs-url> with no value.

Clearly this points to some deeper issue. Suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flash Builder, this value is edited through the project properties under the Flex Build Paths menus. Normally you should see your referenced library here. Double click on the "Link Type" line. Be sure link type is setted to RSL and click the Add button on the right to add a new URL path for your RSL. I suggest you use you main SWF root as it's simplier (ex : myRSLlibrary.swf).